# update a whole column with the values of another column of another table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table named table1 like this:

column1 column2 .. columnX Name     otherColumns

> ```
>                       John  
>                       Paul  
>                       Paul  
>                       Jimmy  
>                       Fred  
>                       Mary
> ```

I know ONLY the Name column in table1.
So in my application I read the whole Name column and encrypt each value.
Now I have to update the names of table1 with their encrypted values.
What can I do? (sorry for bad format of table..)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have another table with columns like `Name` and `EncryptedName`, you can do the `update` with a `join`:

```
update table1 t1 join
       NamePairs np
       on t1.name = np.name
    set t1.name = np.EncryptedName;
```